# Populate excel from epplus on windows app

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a windows app that opens excel.  The user can then decide to save it.
This uses Interop and is very slow when we have over 100 rows.  I'm experimenting with EPPlus and see how to save directly to a file.  But I don't want to do that, I need to open Excel from the app.  So I'm thinking to write out the worksheet using EPPlus (thus saving time) and then copying the whole worksheet into Excel and open it.  Does that make sense?  Are there examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I've used EPPlus and it's a great tool.

I'm a little confused by your question, so let me ask some clarifying questions.

1. Why are you launching excel from your app? Is it to edit some kind of file your program generates, or just random files the user wants to edit?
2. Once the user is finished editing the file, do you need to read it back into your app? If so, that can also be done with EPPlus.

Once I know more about what exactly you're trying to do, I'll be glad to help you.

--John

Comment: 1. We have data in a grid which we are exporting to excel.  So I hit an export button and excel opens with the data.  At this point I can save it to a file or just close it to dismiss it.  2.We're not reading it back, we're simply giving the user the option to save it.

Comment: Also, the only thing I'm trying to do is improve performance.  I can't change the appearance or behavior of the app.